# Required argument 'rejectLevels' (pos 2) not found OpenCV Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a small script where I am passing in an image from picamera on a raspberry pi to a stream to OpenCV. Once OpenCV has the image it should look for faces using haar cascade method. If I separate out the face detection, the code will run fine, reads in an image and uploads to remote server as is intended. When I put the face detection in I get the following error:

flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE

TypeError: Required argument 'rejectLevels' (pos 2) not found

This is the code:

```
current_time = time.time()
endtime = current_time + 30

stream  = io.BytesIO()

CAMERA_WIDTH = 640
CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

while current_time <= endtime:
    timeStamp = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S', time.localtime(current_time))

    with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
        cam.rotation = 270
        cam.resolution = (CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT)
        cam.capture(stream, format='bmp')

    data = np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)
    stream.seek(0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbours=5,
        minSize=(30,30),
        flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))
```

I'm not sure exactly what the error is telling me, some advice would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your parameters, change `minNeighbours` to `minNeighbors`.

Comment: Glad to see it helped. I had the same confusing error message when trying to make minSize values variable and forgetting to cast them to integer ;-)

Comment: I got my example from a tutorial that included that typo apparently.